# Vue use v-for to iterate over an nested array of API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm starting to learn vue, I was trying to practice a little bit and i got stuck with the for-loops.

I'm making a call to an api I've developed to understand better the data handling. The output of the call is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "ID1",
        "customerID": "ASDF",
        "purchases": [
            {
                "laptop": "DELL",
                "price": "500"
            },
            {
                "monitor": "DELL",
                "price": "200"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "ID2",
        "customerID": "FDSA",
        "purchases": [
            {
                "laptop": "MacBook",
                "price": "1800"
            },
            {
                "monitor": "DELL",
                "price": "300"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The purpose I have is to use v-for to go through the array of purchases, so that it can display the contents of the array for each entry in the json.

The vue template I'm using is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card" v-for="data in purchases" :key="data.purchases">
        <div class="card-image">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-content">
                <p class="title is-4">PURCHASES</p>
                <div
                  class="columns is-variable is-1-mobile is-0-tablet is-3-desktop is-8-widescreen is-2-fullhd"
                >
                  <div class="column">Laptop: {{data.purchases[0].laptop}}</div>
                  <div class="column">Monitor: {{data.purchases[0].monitor}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script in the vue file:

```
<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  setup() {
    const purchases = ref([]);
    const API_url = "http://localhost:8383/purchases";

    async function getData() {
      const reponse = await fetch(API_url);
      const json = await reponse.json();
      purchases.value = json;
      console.log(purchases);
    }

    getData();

    return {
      purchases,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I know I'm only showing the first element of the array and that's precisely my question, how can I go through the whole array with the v-for.

I would very much appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another nested `v-for` to loop through `data.purchases` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card" v-for="data in purchases" :key="data.purchases">
        <div class="card-image">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-content">
                <p class="title is-4">PURCHASES</p>
                <div
                  class="columns is-variable is-1-mobile is-0-tablet is-3-desktop is-8-widescreen is-2-fullhd"
                >
                <template v-for="purchase  in data.purchases">
                  <div class="column">Laptop: {{purchase.laptop}}</div>
                  <div class="column">Monitor: {{purchase.monitor}}</div>
               </template>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```